# Ajax loading data from controller in view with 'loading' message

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, curl

Now I'm loading data from cURL in my controller and showing it in my view file but loading from cURL take long time so my webiste is loading very long too.

I want to create loading effect, just load all of my page with "Loading, please wait." message untill cURL data will be available, and after it hide loading message and show my data.

How should I do this?

My code:

**Controller:**

```
public function open_inventory($steam_id, $appid = 730, $contextid = 2)
{
    $data = array("steamid" => $steam_id, "appid" => $appid);

    $cache_file = $this->config->item('inv_dir')."/".$data['steamid']."_".$data['appid'].".json";

    if (file_exists($cache_file) && (filemtime($cache_file) > (time() - 60 * 60 ))) // 1 hour cache
    {
       $output = file_get_contents($cache_file);
    }
    else
    {
        // out-of-date
        $data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

        $ch = curl_init('http://localhost:3000');                                                                      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
        );
        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        file_put_contents($cache_file, $output, LOCK_EX);
    }

    $json = json_decode($output,true);

    if($json['data'])
    {
        return $json;
    }

    return false;
}
```

`$items` in view is `$json['data']` in controller.

**View:**

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
    <div class="item-slot animated zoomIn" data-id="<?= $item['id'] ?>
        <p><?= $item['name'] ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Regards.

Comment: Do you send a request to your controller by using Ajax ?

Comment: @Matt.k I've never work with **Ajax**, that is why I ask here. I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach that you can apply is using **Ajax**.

**AJAX** is an abbreviation standing for **Asynchronous JavaScript and XML** and this technology helps us to load data from the server without a browser page refresh. In your case once the javascript ajax file is loaded, you send an Ajax call to the route that you have your controller in. In your controller you can return data in JSON ,XML,HTML ,... and in success call back function(a function to be called if the request succeeds) you will get your data from server as first parameter then you can hide your waiting and append data you get to DOM element.

 
HTML :

```
<div id="wait-container">
  Please wait....
  <div class="spinner">
  </div> 
</div>
<div id="items"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
     // data that you can send to the server 
     var data = {key1 :'value1',key2:'value2'} ;
     console.log("Data :",data);


      $.ajax({ url: '/path_to_your_php_controller', //replace your url
                data: data ,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    //here hide wait-container
                     $("#wait-container").hide();
                     console.log(response);
                     var string = '';
                     $.map( response, function( val) {
                        // Generate Html
                        string += "<div class='item-slot animated zoomIn' data-id='" + val.id + "'><p>" + val.name + "</p></div>";
                     });
                      //add generated Html to the element.
                      $("#items").html(string);

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                        alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                        alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                        alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                        alert('Time out error.');
                    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                        alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                    } else {
                        alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                    }
                }
        });
})
$(document).on("click",".item-slot",function() {
    alert($(this).data('id'));
});
```

PHP :

```
 <?php
    public function open_inventory()
    {
       // your code here 

       // array of object 
        $arr = array ({'id'=>123,'name'=>'name 1'},{'id'=>2345,'name'=>'name 2'},{'id'=>3423,'name'=>'name 3'},);

       echo json_encode($arr); 
    }

?>
```

Here is an example you may find helpful to understand  http://jsfiddle.net/tg5op333/21/

Comment: I tried to do with `POST` in my controller and it's return now `parsererror`. What is wrong?

Comment: The reason to get that error is becuase you  return a string or another fomat , it is not really Json, so the parser fails. So,remove the dataType: json property, it will not parse it as Json to see if you get your response back. then if it was string you can convert that to json object by using JSON.parse(response);

Comment: `jQuery` code should be inside of `$(document).ready(function(){})`?

Comment: yes when all the DOM elements can be accessed then when we get back or response we have an access to our element to append new HTML to it.

Comment: Now it is loading fine, but I had before ajax `click` method on `item-slot` class, now it doesn't working. What is wrong?