# Send javascript object to the server then handle it with php and replace .js file content with this object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to update existing .js file on the server with ajax and php the whole content of the .js file must be replaced with the created object `objcurrency`

The Idea is that index.html page is the website which makes ajax request for data.js every minute and inside this data.js there is object with currency rates strings.

And i have panel.html that is accessed with username and password where i can change these currency rates string on the server.
So when i want to change the currency rates people who have opened the website will get currency rates that i updated instead of refreshing the page

```
    function ajaxPost(obj){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "js/data.js",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        dataType: 'json'    
        });
}



 $(document).ready(function(){      
                $('#update').on('click', function(){
                    var objrates = {
                        EURbuy : $('#eurbuy').val(),
                        EURsell : $('#eursell').val(),
                        USDbuy : $('#usdbuy').val(),
                        USDbuy : $('#usdbuy').val()
                    };
                    ajaxPost(objrates);
                });                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            });
```

Edits:

Searched some things and came to this so far now i have to add php code that replaces `data.js`(file content) on the server with `$json`

```
<?php 
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

?>
```

Comment: Why would you send a second request to the server? The first request with your data in it should be enough for the server to take the data and insert it into a file. Can you show the server side code you're working with?

Comment: what do you mean by second request i can se only one ajax request in my  code

Comment: Success function is a call back function that will be called when your request is successful it means you send a request to your server (ajax's url) and after processing on your server-side you return a data from your server and then it goes to success call back function where you have an access to data that has been sent from server.

Comment: i dont have written any php yet im just trying to figure the problem way of doing my job after ive done my server side ill start writing php for the server the handle the request

Comment: @GeorgiAntonov In your `success` callback you have a comment `//pass to php that handles the ajax request and updates the already existing data.js file`. But you're already passing the data you need in the ajax request itself - the success callback only happens after the server successfully responds to that request. So it looks like you're already doing everything you need to do on the client side, now you need to add the server side code.

Although you probably don't want the `dataType` to be `script`, but instead whatever data type you're expecting to receive from the server (`json` maybe?)

Comment: i understand so data:obj line sends the js object

and now i have to write the server side and then do something in the success function

Comment: what language are you using for your server-side ?

Comment: php but im really new and will read some articles about how to handle this js object  and then put it inside the data.js file while replacing the previous object

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36298803/6106583, you need to replace your object script inside your controller

Comment: let me clearify all i want is to replace content of a js file which is on the server with the object created from the client side the idea is that clients to the website will make ajax requests every 1 minute to get my currency rates and when  i want to change them via client side panel the clients would not need to refresh the webpage